# jQuery select button from the closest <td>

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this:

```
<div id="somehting">
 <table>
    <tr>
       <td>
         <button id="example">...</button>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="text" class="text"/>
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want to get the button enabled/disabled when I have a keydown-event in the inputfield. To do so I put following listeners to the code:

```
$('#something').on('keydown', ".text", function(){   
   $(this).closest("td").find('#example').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

But it does not work. How do I select the button in the td before the td of the inputfield?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `button` is in the same `tr` not in `td`, so you need to find the `tr` of the `input` element then find the `button` inside it

```
$(this).closest("tr").find('#example').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Note: If you have an ID then there is no need to use any other selector, just use the id selector. But if the `tr` structure is repeated then you will have multiple elements with the same id which is not valid so use a class attribute for the `button` instead of `id`.

So

```
<button class="example">...</button>
```

then

```
$(this).closest("tr").find('.example').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have used wrong parent selector in event delegation for textbox keydown.You have div id `somehting` and in event you are using `something`.try this:

```
 $('#somehting').on('keydown', ".text", function(){   
    $(this).closest("#somehting").find('#example').removeAttr('disabled');
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LMp8J/5/)**